# In Processing 4, how do I make a ball sprite have a random chance to bounce left or right off a platform

Tags: processing

I have a ball sprite and I need it to have a 50/50 chance to bounce off a platform sprite. Here is the code:

```
 bally=bally+3;
    ballx=ballx+3;
    ballx += xspd;
    bally += yspd;
    if(bally > 580 && bally <590 && ballx < mouseX+300 && ballx > mouseX-150){
      yspd*=-3;
      
    }
     else if(bally > 580 && bally <590 && ballx < mouseX+150 && ballx > mouseX){
      yspd*=+3;
      
      
    }
    if(ballx > 900){
      xspd*=-3;
    }
    if(ballx < 0){
      xspd*=+3;
    }
    if(bally < 0 && bally > 700){
      state=LOSE;
    }
```

This code make the ball bounce off the walls but once it bounces off the platform at the top it only bounces to the right. I need it to be a 50/50 chance to bounce either left or right. Thanks

I tried to make an else if statement before but that didn't work, along with changing the xspd variable in said else if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a source of [random](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html):

```
var randNum = random(0, 100);
if (randNum < 50) {
   text("Heads", 200, 200);
   direction = 1;
} else {
   text("Tails", 200, 200);
   direction = -1;
}
```

Use this to chose your sign. That should let chance choose your direction.

Comment: This works great except when i set the direction = to yspd*=-1 or 1 it doesn't make the ball bounce up it instead goes through the platofrm. Which is strange because normally that makes it go up.

Comment: Not sure what “the platform” is.

Comment: its a sprite of a rectangle

Comment: Would that be the mouseX -150 0 150 300 thing? Surprised mouseY isn't involved in it.